# How to reverse the list inside django template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list and I wanted to order by descinding in django-html template,
How can I do it ?

**This is my template code**

```
{% for unique_date in unique_dates %}
    <th>{{unique_date}}</th>
{% endfor %}
```

**And this is my view file**

```
unique_dates = list({a.date for a in attendances})
unique_dates.sort()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort it in reverse with:

```
unique_dates = sorted({a.date for a in attendances}, reverse=False)
# no extra sort needed
```

This will thus sort the `a.date` items in *reversed* order, so with the largest (latest) one first, and the smallest (earliest) one last.

An alternative is to work with the [**`{% for … in … reversed %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

```
{# rendering in reverse #}
{% for unique_date in unique_dates reversed %}
    <th>{{ unique_date }}</th>
{% endfor %}
```